# swift 3+, URLsession, in the background fails apparently at random

Tags: ios, swift, background, urlsession

I am fairly new to swift(1 week) and iOS programming, and my problem is that I seem to miss some basic understanding. Below you see a function that is triggered by a background notification. I can and have verified that I receive the background notification reliably and the app comes active (printout of the raw data values on the console) As long as the app is in the foreground everything is working just as expected, it gets fired, and sends a single https request. The background triggers come on a timer every minute.

Now the whole thing changes when the app enters into the background. In this case I am still getting the triggers through the notification (console printout) and I can see in the debugger the same function that works like a charm in the foreground stumbles. It still works, it still gets fired, but a data packet is sent only so often, randomly as it seems between 2 and 30 minutes.

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "org.x.Reporter")
class queryService {
    let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: config)
    var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?


    var errorMessage = ""


    func getSearchResults(baseURL: String, searchTerm: String) {
        dataTask?.cancel()
        config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
        config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10

        if var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://host.com/reportPosition.php") {
            urlComponents.query = "\(searchTerm)"
            guard let url = urlComponents.url else { return }

            dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url)
        }
        // 7
        dataTask?.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dataTaskWithCompletion` so you can see what's going wrong in the error.

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL.init(string: "")!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            // Error
        }
    }.resume()
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask

**EDIT**

What you want to do is for background you get `completions` via `delegate` call backs so when you `init` ur `URLSession` do so using the following `func`

```
URLSession.init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.init(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.init())
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411597-init

Then conform ur class to the `URLSessionDelegate` like so

```
class queryService, URLSessionDelegate {
```

then implement the `delegate` methods listed here for call backs

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondelegate

**EDIT2**

Here is good tutorial about it 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/158106/urlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: I actually had this first, but iOS told me that in the background you can't have a completion handler:  
"exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Completion handler blocks are not supported in background sessions. Use a delegate instead."

Comment: Right. Have you enabled `Background Fetch` under the `Capabilities` option in the project. https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Yes, I did, I checked again. And just as a clarification, the code works, just not. every time it is being fired.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Good idea, alas, it does not seem to help either. I implemented all three delegate functions and have breakpoints on those, yet, they are not being called, ever. Not if it works, nor if it fails.

Comment: When you create a new DataTask conform to it's delegate aswell. `URLSessionTaskDelegate` see if those get hit.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate